# MsBuild command ignoring location in publish profile

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, msbuild, publish

I have a VS 2012 solution with asp.net mvc c# site and I'm using it's publish profile with msbuild command. On my local machine the files are published to the directory specified in publish profile but on server they go to the project bin directory.

I'm running the following via MSBuild:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe C:\WebSites\EMS.sln  /p:Configuration=Release /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0  /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=true /p:PublishProfile=C:\WebSites\EMSMVC\Properties\PublishProfiles\EMS_Auto.pubxml
```

Here's the publish profile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
This file is used by the publish/package process of your Web project. You can customize the behavior of this process
by editing this MSBuild file. In order to learn more about this please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>
      Images
    </ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>C:\Apps\NEW_PUBLISH</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

We are using .NET Framework 4.5; IIS version on my PC is 7.5; Visual studio 12, Premium edition.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I think PublishProfile is the name of the profile to publish, not the location. The name of the file of the .pubxmlfile

Comment: PublishProfile can be name of the publish profile or you can also provide a full path to a .pubxml file, but problem shouldn't be there since this command is working on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is an universal solution but I have seen something similar here on site, used it and that solved our problem: since the Visual studio used for editing and deployment in local is ,as I mentioned,VS 2012 or version 11, I have to copy folder Web from local C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web in location on server: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ (there was only folder WebApplications) and now it's working fine.